# How to run the Google Text to Speech API behind corporate proxy

Tags: google-text-to-speech

I m trying to run a Node Js application which uses the Google Text To Speech API client library. But since i am running the application behind a corporate proxy i gets connection refused error.Please let me know whats the IP and Port for which the firewall to be opened for enabling the traffic to TTS API so that i can reach out to my company firewall team to enable the traffic to the respective IP and port. I couldn't find any documentation in the official google pages for the same.

Comment: Try running behind a VPN if you can get in installed?